# Getting the location of an inf from ManagementObjectSearcher

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm using the below code to iterate through all my device drivers in windows.  I'm able to find the INF name, however, i'm unable to find the INF location.  Any help is awesome.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
            new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPSignedDriver");
foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
{
    if(obj["DriverProviderName"] != null)
    {
        foreach (PropertyData prop in obj.Properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", prop.Name, prop.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Output: InfName: hal.inf

Where is the location of hal.inf?  I'm trying to create an application that will backup all of device drivers.

Hal.inf is just an example.

Property outpot example:

```
Caption    
ClassGuid   {4D36E968-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
CompatID    PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0422&REV_A1
CreationClassName   
Description NVIDIA GeForce 8400 GS 
DeviceClass DISPLAY
DeviceID    PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0422&SUBSYS_C7323842&REV_A1\4&31ADF711&0&0008
DeviceName  NVIDIA GeForce 8400 GS 
DevLoader   
DriverDate  20120515000000.******+***
DriverName  
DriverProviderName  NVIDIA
DriverVersion   6.14.13.142
FriendlyName    
HardWareID  PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0422&SUBSYS_C7323842&REV_A1
InfName oem25.inf
InstallDate 
IsSigned    True
Location    PCI bus 1, device 0, function 0
Manufacturer    NVIDIA
Name    
PDO \Device\NTPNP_PCI0021
Signer  Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility Publisher
Started 
StartMode   
Status  
SystemCreationClassName 
SystemName
```

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves me correct the *.inf which was used during install of the driver gets converted into windows's driver store, an oem[0-9]{1,3}.inf file, which you see listed in your output. I just now used the devcon program to find my video cards hwid and then used devcon again to list the driverfiles.

In the output you will notice the path reference to the System32/DriverStore. This actually contains the original *.inf file used during the install. :) Its 1:1 just diffed nv_disp.inf against my oem#.inf. Devcon really provides you a complete listing of driver files, unlike my experiences with wmi and others.

This is the refference im talking about
    C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_disp.inf_amd64_neutral_671aa18aef114cc2\

So its pretty simple! Snag your HWID | devcon driverfiles | cleanup the results, add a tiny bit of logic | tar old-driver.tar filelist.txt

Restoring or doing something usefull with these backups would be something very different. Everytime you update drivers it will add a new driverstore folder, figureing out which one is the most recent wouldn't be difficult at all. So in theory you don't really need todo anything by get some folder stats and backup the right one. You could also use PnPutil to loop though and attempt to delete all oem*.inf driver packages, it can't delete active packages so risk is minimal, but it might cleanup the driverstore somewhat.

You might also be isnterest in my Geforce Driver Check script available on github.

You will need to download their 500meg Driver Dev Kit ISO and extract+rename both devcon binaries (devconx64.exe and devcon.exe i think) Devcon can do everything the "Device Manager GUI" can do from the CMD line.

```
$ devcon driverfiles PCI\\VEN_10DE\&DEV_1184
PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1184&SUBSYS_37743842&REV_A1\4&2F1C4782&0&0018
    Name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 770
    Driver installed from C:\Windows\INF\oem8.inf [Section090]. 53 file(s) used by driver:
        C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Drs\dbInstaller.exe
        C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Drs\nvdrsdb.bin
        C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_disp.inf_amd64_neutral_671aa18aef114cc2\NvCplSetupEng.exe
        C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\Nvd3d9wrap.dll
        C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\detoured.dll
        C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\nvdxgiwrap.dll
        C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\Nvd3d9wrapx.dll
        C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\detoured.dll
        C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\nvdxgiwrapx.dll
        C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\license.txt
        C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI\MCU.exe
        C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI\nvdebugdump.exe
        C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI\nvidia-smi.1.pdf
        C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI\nvidia-smi.exe
        C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI\nvml.dll
        C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\OpenCL\OpenCL.dll
        C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\OpenCL\OpenCL64.dll
        C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\nvlddmkm.sys
        C:\Windows\system32\NvFBC64.dll
        C:\Windows\system32\NvIFR64.dll
        C:\Windows\system32\NvIFROpenGL.dll
        C:\Windows\system32\nvEncodeAPI64.dll
        C:\Windows\system32\nvapi64.dll
        C:\Windows\system32\nvcompiler.dll
        C:\Windows\system32\nvcuda.dll
        C:\Windows\system32\nvcuvenc.dll
        C:\Windows\system32\nvcuvid.dll
        C:\Windows\system32\nvd3dumx.dll
        C:\Windows\system32\nvinfo.pb
        C:\Windows\system32\nvinitx.dll
        C:\Windows\system32\nvoglshim64.dll
        C:\Windows\system32\nvoglv64.dll
        C:\Windows\system32\nvopencl.dll
        C:\Windows\system32\nvumdshimx.dll
        C:\Windows\system32\nvwgf2umx.dll
        C:\Windows\SysWow64\NvFBC.dll
        C:\Windows\SysWow64\NvIFR.dll
        C:\Windows\SysWow64\NvIFROpenGL.dll
        C:\Windows\SysWow64\nvEncodeAPI.dll
        C:\Windows\SysWow64\nvapi.dll
        C:\Windows\SysWow64\nvcompiler.dll
        C:\Windows\SysWow64\nvcuda.dll
        C:\Windows\SysWow64\nvcuvenc.dll
        C:\Windows\SysWow64\nvcuvid.dll
        C:\Windows\SysWow64\nvd3dum.dll
        C:\Windows\SysWow64\nvinit.dll
        C:\Windows\SysWow64\nvoglshim32.dll
        C:\Windows\SysWow64\nvoglv32.dll
        C:\Windows\SysWow64\nvopencl.dll
        C:\Windows\SysWow64\nvumdshim.dll
        C:\Windows\SysWow64\nvwgf2um.dll
        C:\Windows\system32\nvdispco6433193.dll
        C:\Windows\system32\nvdispgenco6433193.dll
1 matching device(s) found.

Device Console Help:
devcon.exe [-r] [-m:\\<machine>] <command> [<arg>...]
-r           Reboots the system only when a restart or reboot is required.
<machine>    Specifies a remote computer.
<command>    Specifies a Devcon command (see command list below).
<arg>...     One or more arguments that modify a command.
For help with a specific command, type: devcon.exe help <command>
classfilter          Add, delete, and reorder class filters.
classes              List all device setup classes.
disable              Disable devices.
driverfiles          List installed driver files for devices.
drivernodes          List driver nodes of devices.
enable               Enable devices.
find                 Find devices.
findall              Find devices, including those that are not currently attached.
help                 Display Devcon help.
hwids                List hardware IDs of devices.
install              Install a device manually.
listclass            List all devices in a setup class.
reboot               Reboot the local computer.
remove               Remove devices.
rescan               Scan for new hardware.
resources            List hardware resources for devices.
restart              Restart devices.
sethwid              Modify Hardware ID's of listed root-enumerated devices.
stack                List expected driver stack for devices.
status               List running status of devices.
update               Update a device manually.
updateni             Manually update a device (non interactive).
dp_add               Adds (installs) a third-party (OEM) driver package.
dp_delete            Deletes a third-party (OEM) driver package.
dp_enum              Lists the third-party (OEM) driver packages installed on this machine.
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve information regarding the driver file itself, query the [`Win32_SystemDriver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394472.aspx) table. The driver path is given by the `PathName` property.

Comment: Evan, that doesn't actually display the INF

Comment: The INF should be the same name with the .inf extension.

Comment: Evan, have you used this before?  Win32_PnPSignedDriverCIMDataFile   I think this is what i'm looking for but I can't find an example

Comment: That represents the actual data file contents: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394355(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The Win32_PnPSignedDriverCIMDataFile association WMI class finds all binary files associated with a PnP driver.

Comment: I'm pretty sure thats what I want

Comment: The binary file is the .sys file, not the .inf.

Comment: Okay, well do you have a better WMI that sounds like it's better?  Because I cant find one